# How to make vEthernet (Default Switch) appear in Network Connections of Control Panel again?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, network-adapter, switch, control-panel

In my Windows 11 machine I do not see the vEthernet (Default Switch) shown in the Network Connections of the Control Center (Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections) or Settings (Network & internet > Advanced network settings > Network adapters). I only see some others:

[Control Center Network adapter view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3onX.png)

If I list the interfaces with Power Shell, I do see the NIC (here index 23):

```
PS> Get-NetAdapter

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       
Ethernet                  Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V      19 Disconnected 
vEthernet (Default Swi... Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter             23 Up           
Bluetooth Network Conn... Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Netw...      11 Disconnected 
Wi-Fi                     Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265           4 Up
```

It also works fine in Hyper-V such that I get Internet access in my virtual machines.

Also if I create new switches in the Hyper-v manager, the switches appear in the Control Center.

Since it is very comfortable to see properties and the like in the control center I would like to have the vEthernet (Default Switch) appear there again. It once upon a time also was there, I don't know why its not shown anymore.

I tried de-installing all Windows features that use the vEthernet (Default Switch) (WSL, Container, Sandbox, Hyper-v). vEthernet (Default Switch) did disappear also from Get-NetAdapter. The After reinstalling Hyper-V the vEthernet (Default Switch) is still missing in the Control Center.

Any idea of what I could do to get the vEthernet (Default Switch) back visible?